# JS / CSS onmouseover issue - flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a nice Transition, when someone hovers over one of the 3 div containers. I am changing the classes with js, the classes on the other hand have a Transition or Animation.

You can look at the live version here: [LINK](http://maler1.calmarsolutions.ch/index.html)

**This is the HTML and Inline Javascript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Schwarz & Torf Maler AG</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-12 header_div">
        <h1 class="col-12 header_title">Schwarz & Torf Maler AG</h1>
        <h3 class="col-12 header_subtitle">Wir Malen wo andere nur zuschauen</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2"></div>

    <div class="col-2" id="content_1" onmouseover="mouseOver('content_1', 'content_2', 'content_3')" onmouseout="mouseOut('content_1', 'content_2', 'content_3')">
        <div class="content_area content_col_1 shadowbox_red">
            <div class="content_title">
                <h2>Palette</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1"></div>

    <div class="col-2" id="content_2" onmouseover="mouseOver('content_2', 'content_1', 'content_3')" onmouseout="mouseOut('content_2', 'content_1', 'content_3')">
        <div class="content_area content_col_2 shadowbox_blue">
            <div class="content_title">
                <h2>Offerte</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1"></div>

    <div class="col-2" id="content_3" onmouseover="mouseOver('content_3', 'content_1', 'content_2')" onmouseout="mouseOut('content_3', 'content_1', 'content_2')">
        <div class="content_area content_col_3 shadowbox_green">
            <div class="content_title">
                <h2>Vor Ort</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <script>
        function mouseOver(content, content_reduce1, content_reduce2) {
            console.log(content + " selected");
            console.log(document.getElementById(content));
            document.getElementById(content).setAttribute("class", "col-5-trans");
            document.getElementById(content_reduce1).setAttribute("class", "col-0");
            document.getElementById(content_reduce2).setAttribute("class", "col-0");
        }
        function mouseOut(content, content_reset1, content_reset2) {
            console.log(content + " deselected");
            setInterval(function(){
                document.getElementById(content).setAttribute("class", "col-2");
                document.getElementById(content_reset1).setAttribute("class", "col-2");
                document.getElementById(content_reset2).setAttribute("class", "col-2");
            },2000);

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**These here are the relevant parts from the CSS file:**

```
/*GRID_COLUMNS*/
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

    .col-0 {
    width: 8.33%;

    animation-name: col-0-anim;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

    @keyframes col-0-anim {
        0% {
            width: 8.33%;
        }
        100% {
            width: 0%;
        }
    }

    .col-5-trans {
        width: 16.66%;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-out; /* Safari */
        transition: width 2s ease-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .col-5-trans:hover {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
/*END GRID_COLUMNS*/
```

**Here the CONTENT Area CSS:**

```
/*CONTENT AREA*/
.content_area {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;

    background-image: url("images/background_exp.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
    .content_area .content_title {
        position: relative;
        overflow: visible;
        height: 100%;
        width: 45%;
        float: right;
    }

    .content_area h2 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: 100px;

        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
        white-space: nowrap;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 5em;

        -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are trying to mimic Twitter Bootstrap's grid system's principle, with variable column widths on hover.

You have to options:

### 1. *Doing-It-Wrong™*

You shouldn't use `col-*` system here at all but, as an exercise, here is the logic your `JavaScript` should follow in order to achieve this effect:

1. make all your columns equal at start (make them `col-4`)
2. make column wider on `mouseenter` and the other two columns narrower (make all `col-3` and hovered one `col-6`)
3. make all three columns equal on `mouseleave` (make all `col-4`)
4. when leaving a column and entering another at the same time, make sure `mouseenter` fires after the `mouseleave` (on all devices)
5. animate the `width` property of columns with *A-Nice-Transition™*

Alternatively to `5)`, you could use jQuery's `animate()`, but animating `width` might produce poor results on devices with limited resources and your transitions are not guaranteed to always be smooth. You're safer using CSS transitions.

I only listed the programming logic for the solution above and not the code itself because I strongly advise **against** this approach. If are sure you want to go this way, I can provide it.

Why do I advise against it? Because the same result can be achieved much cleaner through CSS...

### 2. `flexbox` to the rescue

It's faster, lighter on the browser and renders more smoothly on all devices. Besides, you don't need to worry about the order of `JavaScript` events.

If you're worried about browser-compat, it currently stands at [97.38%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (prefixed). It has better support than [`box-hadow`](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow), which you seem to use quite a bit.
Here's the code:

```css
.roW {
  margin:1rem auto;
  /* change to desired height */
  min-height:calc(100vh - 2rem); 
  
  /* don't forget to prefix all CSS at https://autoprefixer.github.io/ */
  display: flex; 
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}
.columN {
  background-color: #999;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: 33%;
  
  /* A-Nice-Transition™ */ 
  transition: flex-grow .5s  cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2,1), max-width .5s  cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2,1);
}
.columN:hover {
  
  /* change to make hovered columns wider */
  flex-grow: 2; 
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="roW">
  <div class="columN"></div>
  <div class="columN"></div>
  <div class="columN"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** the `max-width` might seem unnecessary, but it's there to keep columns same width when the contents differ in length (otherwise they would self-adjust to best fit the display of contents).

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the Flexbox "stuff". it is in fact quite new to me, and you just gave me the perfect reason to learn it. I also researched what VH/VW and REM stands for - rem is a little bit weird - but VH/VW are so freaking useful :D
You see - I am quite new to developing.

I will come back, to write some questions, when I can't finish it by myselfes :)
Thanks for taking the time :D

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad you found it useful. Please make a habit of marking answers useful or not by voting them up/down so future visitors spend less time looking for the most helpful answer. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use JavaScript here. A CSS-only solution is just fine for your case:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.col:hover {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of using floating elements, I would suggest you, to put your cols inside a container and use flexbox to place them perfectly side-by-side.

---

### Keep position and make the columns less wide on hover

If you want to keep the position of each elements on hover, and make the columns less wide, you can do it like this instead:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.col:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
}
.col:last-child {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: initial; // Reset left
}

.col:hover {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are correct for makeing the element wider. but I also need to make the other columns less wide, when the mouse hovers over the one element. that's why pure CSS won't work sadly.

Comment: Check my second solution in the updated answer. Is that what you're looking for? :)